# How to stop Script Injection in field collection

Tags: 7, nodes

I have created Field Collection with Text and image. Now if i insert  java script like

```
<script type="text/javascript" >alert("hacked")</script>
```

How to skip this 
same i did for node body and title using hook_node_presave($node) and its working but for field collection it is not working.
Below is my code

```
function mydrupal_common_node_presave($node) {
  if($node->type == "test") {
    $node->title = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $node->title);
    $node->body['und'][0]['value']=preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $node->body['und'][0]['value']);
    if(is_array($node->field_activity_images['und'])){
      foreach($node->field_activity_images['und'] as $key => $value){
        $location= $node->field_activity_images['und'][$key]['field_location']['und'][0]['value'];
        $node->field_activity_images['und'][$key]['field_location']['und'][0]['value']=preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $location);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using drupal 7.59

Comment: I think you should report this to the maintainer of the module

Comment: You probably should be using hook_js_alter().

Comment: Is there any hook that can be edit field collection fields before node saving?